# C# default interface implementation - can't override

Tags: c#, default-interface-member

I'm following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods to use default interface implementation feature. I've copied a code that defines a default implementation in interface `IA` and then overrides it in interface `IB`:

```
interface I0
{
    void M() { Console.WriteLine("I0"); }
}

interface I1 : I0
{
    override void M() { Console.WriteLine("I1"); }
}
```

But it gives be an error `CS0106 The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item` and a warning `CS0108 'I1.M()' hides inherited member 'I0.M()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended`. `TargetFramework` is set to `net5.0`, `LangVersion` is `latest`. Why it's not working even if it's described in official docs?

Comment: is it ok for an interface method signature to have a body?

Comment: @ilkerkaran Yeap, see the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods (C#8)

Comment: @HimBromBeere, thanks for the heads-up. Darn synthetic sugars :)

Comment: There is a reference [in the tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/default-interface-methods-versions) also

Comment: I can't find any better documentation on this language feature.  It seems that this design proposal document is the best MSDN has to offer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently, examples with `override` keyword are incorrect, this keyword must be removed. Also, it's only working if method interface is specified explicitly:

```
interface I0
{
    void M() { Console.WriteLine("I0"); }
}

interface I1 : I0
{
    void I0.M() { Console.WriteLine("I1"); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#overrides-in-interfaces) it says "Implicit overrides are not permitted."

Confusingly the `IC` interface that follows it does not repeat that statement, *while using the implicit approach*, making it *look like the implicit approach is valid*. And `IC` seems to be the interface that you copied from.

Comment: I've also tried explicit approach but it also gives compiler error